# Database query to fetch records within bounds

Tags: java, c#, google-maps, location, cllocationmanager

I am passing `top bottom left right` co-ordinates to the database query. My table has latitude and longitude columns. How can I filter the records coming in the map view port. What will be the algorithm?

Comment: hey saranya, does my answer worked for you ?

Comment: Yes your solution is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

as you written you have bound values:

so you are having south West, and north East values,

south West have latitude and longitude, and  north east having latitude and longitude,

using this you can write query to find which latitude and longitude from database fall into that bound,

SW = south west
NE = north east

```
 "SELECT * FROM location_master WHERE latitude > '".SW_lat."' AND latitude < '".NE_lat."' AND longitude > '".SW_lng."' AND longitude < '".NE_lng."' "
```